# How do I add a bash module to my startup profile?

Tags: software-installation

- How do I install the bash module that came in the zipfile that appears in this page?

http://ss64.com/pass/command-line.html

- How do I install any module (not necessarily in startup profile)?
- How do I install modules from Github?

Many thanks

Comment: using a link that downloads a file to my computer is not nice. Your link should only go to a webpage that describes the program you are trying to use. That webpage in turn would contain instructions that others could read and explain to you in order to help you use you install or use your application.

Comment: Simply add the code to somewhere in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

First, in this case, extract the module from the Zip file to your home directory:

```
#   pipe from-zipfile          a-contained-file         to    a-new-file
unzip -p strongpw.zip strongpw_bash_module/strongpw.bash > ~/strongpw.bash
```

Then add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
. ~/strongpw.bash
```

The contents of `~/.bashrc` are run at the start of every new interactive bash shell.  The `. FILENAME` causes `~/.bashrc` to also include that file within the new shell allowing it to define functions there, in this case `strongpw`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is a neat way of doing it. Can you also give me an example of how to install from github. There are so many good modules in there but I don't know how to install them